# is there any way to convert the columns in Pandas Dataframe using its mirror image Dataframe structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, series

the  df I have is :

```
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  0  0  1
2  0  1  0
3  0  1  1
4  1  0  0
5  1  0  1
6  1  1  0
7  1  1  1
```

I wanted to obtain a Dataframe with columns reversed/mirror image :

```
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  1  1  0
4  0  0  1
5  1  0  1
6  0  1  1
7  1  1  1
```

Is there any way to do that

Comment: Try `df.iloc[:, ::-1]`?

Comment: Please accept one of the provided solutions if you feel your question has been sufficiently answered. That way your question will be removed from the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can check

```
df[:] = df.iloc[:,::-1]
df
Out[959]: 
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  1  1  0
4  0  0  1
5  1  0  1
6  0  1  1
7  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit more verbose, but likely more efficient solution as it doesn't require to rewrite the data. It only renames and reorders the columns:

```
cols = df.columns
df.columns = df.columns[::-1]
df = df.loc[:,cols]
```

Or shorter variant:

```
df = df.iloc[:,::-1].set_axis(df.columns, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  1  1  0
4  0  0  1
5  1  0  1
6  0  1  1
7  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other ways, but here's one solution:

```py
df[df.columns] = df[reversed(df.columns)]
```

Output:

```py
   0  1  2
0  0  0  0
1  1  0  0
2  0  1  0
3  1  1  0
4  0  0  1
5  1  0  1
6  0  1  1
7  1  1  1
```